# Discord.js message repeats after every time executed

Tags: discord.js

Whenever I go to test my bot it works the first time then repeats every time its executed (if the command is used 3 times it repeats 3 times)

```
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content === 'admin') {
    message.channel.send('please type test2');
    bot.on('message', message => {
      if(message.content === 'test2') {
        message.channel.send('ok:D');
        return;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks In advance:)

Comment: Do you have an event listener inside an event listener? i.e. `bot.on('message' ...` inside `bot.on('message' ...`? That's not the correct way to check for responses. You should look into collectors instead: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `if` statements into the `message` event, and put a **[Collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageCollector)** or **[awaitMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)** to collect messages.

Here I used `awaitMessage` to identify that who send message is the same author who sent admin :).

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content == "admin") {
        await message.reply('Enter test2');

        const filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id;
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            maxMatches: 1,
            time: 30000
        }).then(collected => {
            const _first = collected.first().content.toLowerCase();

            if (_first == "test2") {
                message.channel.send("OK!")
            }

        }).catch(() => {
            return message.reply('No answer after 30 seconds, operation canceled.');
        });
    }
})
```

**Stay Safe *$***